# How does subtraction between two Chars work?

Tags: java, char, subtraction

I'm trying to figure out the following code and failing to understand the subtraction operation between two Chars:

```
String s = "rsjrcntuanbqchsfahvijh";
int[] letters = new int[26];
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    letters[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
}
```

I mean, I understand, what the code does: It finds the frequency of each letter of the alphabet in the given String and saves it in an array. But I can't really make sense of the subtraction. Are the unicode values of these two Chars being used for this operation? what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It subtracts the ASCII value of the 2 characters.

A char is actually just stored as a number (its code point value). We have syntax to represent characters like char c = 'A';, but it's equivalent to char c = 65; and 'A' == 65 is true.

So in your case, the value at letters[0] will keep incrementing for every 'a' in the string and so on.

Thus at each position, you get the frequency of each letter.

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII.  A `char` is a UTF-16 codepoint.  That doesn't change the general correctness of this answer, though.